# How can I remove this black shadow from the box?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. Can you help me, how I can fix this black shadow from the letter, that it will look like the other letters? ty guys :)

[As you can see in some the letters H,V,A and W have a black box around them, they are flickering that it will look like a neon sign. hopefully you can help me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2k9o.png)

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
    <h1 class="nav-name">Villains WorldWide</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-left">
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a href="#" class="nav-right"><button>Contact</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <h1 class="neon" data-text="U">T<span class="flicker-fast">H</span>IS IS&nbsp;<span class="flicker-slow">V</span>ILL<span class="flicker-slow">A</span>INS WORLD<span class="flicker-fast">W</span>IDE</h1>
        <img src="Media\VillainsWorldWide_GIF_LOGO_Animation.gif" alt="VillainsWorldWideLogo" class="logo">
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
    background-color: black;
}

.neon {
    font-size: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 75px;
    color: #FFD5FF;   
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    translate: (-50%, -50%);
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 4px #FFD5FF, 2px 0px 4px #FFD5FF, 3px 0px 4px #FFD5FF, 2px 0px 3px #D42CCA, 2px 3px 15px #D42CCA, 2px 0px 15px, 5px 0px 125px, 20px 0vw 200px #D42CCA,40px 0vw 200px #D42CCA;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
}

    
.flicker-slow{
    animation: flicker 3s linear infinite;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .flicker-fast{
    animation: flicker 1s linear infinite;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  @keyframes flicker {
    0%, 19.999%, 22%, 62.999%, 64%, 64.999%, 70%, 100% {
    opacity: .99;
    
    }
    20%, 21.999%, 63%, 63.999%, 65%, 69.999% {
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
  }
```

Comment: this happens due to the * selector. U should change the background of body as black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Besworks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6036546/besworks) suggested and i agree, my previous answer doesn't include a good solution, just a workaround for the real problem, the universal selector:

```
* {
  background-color: black;
}
```

this rule applies for every element on the page, so it's the root cause of the undesired behavior in the flicker classes.

You should avoid this and use the background rule within the body selector, like so:

```
 body {
   background-color: black;
}
```

and lastly, you no longer need the transparent background, like in my previous answer:

```
.flicker-slow{
    /* remove background-color: transparent; */
    animation: flicker 3s linear infinite;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .flicker-fast{
    /* remove background-color: transparent; */
    animation: flicker 1s linear infinite;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

With this change the black shadow should disappear, take a look:
[link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yagobiermann/0tjwrqec/)

This is a simpler and cleaner solution for the real problem, thanks for [@Besworks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6036546/besworks) and [@Servesh-Chaturvedi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16915292/servesh-chaturvedi) who helped me to complement this answer.

Comment: nothing changed...

Comment: This is not a good solution. Brute-forcing the `background-color` of **all** elements (with the `*` rule) is a bad move and this *fix* is just a workaround for the real problem: Poor CSS scoping. @servesh-chaturvedi suggested the right solution in his comment above. Change the background of the `body` element instead and then specifically target any other elements that also need to be black.

Comment: After reading this post again i can say that i agree with you, i will edit my answer to include this solution, thanks for the suggestion, i appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Darlo answered it correctly. I also think you can try changing your span property.

```
     <!-- language: lang-css -->
       span {
          background-color: transparent;
        }
    <!-- end snippet -->
```

Here's an article on CSS cascading orders, this might help.
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span
Span tag is an inline container already, for styling or grouping content/elements.
Your flicker looks eye-catching though. Very nice.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because the span elements are taking the background color from the *.
Try adding to your CSS something along the lines of

```
span{
  background-color:transparent;
}
```